# ASP.NET Membership returning SAME session information for every user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET Membership application. I log in as "JONNY" and this is a success. RUPERT then (from a different PC, at a different location) clicks on the members area and he is not prompted to login but he see's Jonny's profile and information. It's as if Jonny clicked "Remember Me", then Rupert comes along top his SAME machine and clicks the link - here, I would expect Rupert to see Jonny's page as it's on the SAME machine and Jonny hasn't logged out. But these two people are in different locations, on difference machines, different IP's etc.

How can this be?

```
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            // user is logged in here, we know the username is valid...
            var memberStore = new MemberStore();
            var member = memberStore.GetMemberByUsername(model.UserName);

            // but now check if they've confirmed their email
            // if not, sign the session out and show inactive account view...
            if (!member.IsActive)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                return View("AccountNotActive");

            }
            string[] roleNames = Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName);

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

            Settings.Setting.UserSession.Member = member;
            var viewModel = new MyProfileViewModel { Member = memberStore.GetMemberByUsername(model.UserName) };
            viewModel.Role = roleNames[0];

            return View("MyProfile", viewModel);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Settings.Setting.UserSession.Member = null;
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return View("LoggedOut");
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your login code?

Comment: there is no way anyone can answer this without seeing the login code , primarily the code where the  membership token is set

Comment: Sorry - my head is battered! Of course the code would help! Apologies.

Comment: What does `Settings.Setting.UserSession.Member = member;` do?

Comment: It's not too clear I know but it stored a Model from the Core project which is all the clients details, name, address, age, dob etc. etc. they provided at sign up. It retrieves this info from the username provided at login. It's not the actual Membership Member/User. Mmm... could this be getting stored and every user is seeing this? Am I wrong when I thought each visit to the site instantiates a new session, meaning this information would be null until populated?

Comment: Check to see if Member, UserSession, etc. are static.

Comment: Setting class, UserSession and Member are all static! I need to instantiate a new one each time don't I??

Comment: In a website environment, static variables are shared across all users. So if that UserSession.Member is used to identify the current user, then yes, everyone would be treated as the same user. Without more investigation, I can't be sure of what exactly the goal was. A quick fix might be to change UserSession to be a wrapper around HttpContext.Current.Session

Comment: I'll get that changed! The idea is essentially that, a user logs in but that bespoke MEMBER code gives me so much more control/use of the member/user. That make sense what you said about static and shared. I'll look at using the HttpContext.Current.Session. Thank you! Jason I could almost kiss you! Ha. Thanks very much for your advice! I'll know if this works in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing an answer so I can show code. A possible quick fix could look something like this:

```
public static class UserSession
{

    public static SiteMember Member
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["Member"] as SiteMember;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Member"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Static members are ok here because the implementation works on values specific to the current user's session.